# How to increase font size for whole React JS Web App From Single Point

Tags: reactjs

How to increase font size for whole React JS Web App From Single Point
[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RvDPs.png)

Comment: Make default HTML CSS font size make your content font size em and rem. So once HTML font size increases through javascript all relative font increases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
:root {
    --base-font-size: 10px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: var(--base-font-size);
}
```

```js
// get css variable value
const root = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);
console.log("CURRENT FONT SIZE: ", root.getPropertyValue('--base-font-size'))


// set css variable value
document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
    "--base-font-size",
    "50px",
)
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel solution for this is opinion based, You can create a gloabl variable file and import everywhere in your application, and if anything changes related to font then store it in browser, so that whenver user comes back user should get same font.

something like

```
   :root {
      --font-size:20px
    }
```

and after performing click event

```
const handleClick = () => {
  let root = document.documentElement;
  root.style.setProperty('--font-size', 30+"px")
  localStorage.setItem('fontSize', 30+"px")
}
```

and if value is coming from localstorage then set it

```
root.style.setProperty('fontSize', localStorage.getItem('fontSize'))
```

you can perform based on your requirement, and you can use this variable in your css

```
font-size:var(--font-size)
```

Answer (score 0):

Never tried this myself, but I would think at least at minimum it could be done in the index.js or app.js file using useState and a function to set the font size. They would basically cover your whole page.

A real simple example would be:

```
const [fontSize, setFontSize] =useState( *insert your default font size here* )

const handleButton = () => {

setFontSize(fontSize + 1)

}

<nav>
<button onClick={handleButton}/>
</nav>

<App style={{fontSize: {fontSize}}/>
```

If you have any other styling you might have to overide with "!important". Also this would probably be a lot easier with Tailwind CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I recently solved this problem in one of my projects like this:

**index.html**

```html
<style>
    :root {
        --base-font-size: 13.5px;
        font-size: var(--base-font-size);
    }
</style>
```

then use the `rem` in you project to define sizes or calculated values based on `var(--base-font-size)`.

To change the fontsize in your project by (i.e. a click on a button):

**React**

```js
const increaseSize = () => {
    const root = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement)
    let oldpx = Number.parseInt(root.getPropertyValue('--base-font-size').replaceAll('px'));
    root.style.setProperty('--base-font-size', (oldpx + 1) + 'px');
}
```

The variable based and the rem values should change their size according to `--base-font-size` afterwards.